# Furher help on Xen and USB passthrough

Tags: 18.04, usb, virtualization, xen

I know that this is a long-shot, but I have not been able to obtain any help from the Xen community so I wondered if anyone in Ask Ubuntu may be able to help?

I have manged to get Xen installed and running an Ubuntu DomU alongside an Ubuntu Dom0 by using the guidance at..

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen

and..

[How to install Xen Project on Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171864/how-to-install-xen-project-on-ubuntu-server-18-04-3-lts)

I would now like to access USBs on my DomU.

On Dom0, I can attach my USBs.

```
$ sudo xl usbdev-attach ubud1 hostbus=2 hostaddr=36
$ sudo xl usb-list ubud1
Devid  Type         BE  state usb-ver ports
0      qusb         0   1     2       8
  Port 1: Bus 002 Device 025
  Port 2: Bus 002 Device 024
  Port 3:
   …
```

But I can’t see them in my DomU. Any suggestions?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.
Martin...