# How to stop loading Xen 4.9-amd64 on boot

Tags: 18.04, kernel, virtualization, xen

I installed xen on ubuntu following [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171864/how-to-install-xen-project-on-ubuntu-server-18-04-3-lts). Now, when I boot ubuntu 18.04, it takes ages and it says in the beginning:

```
Loading Xen 4.9-amd64 ...
WARNING: no console will be available to OS
Loading Linux 4.15.0-144-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

How can I stop Xen from loading and delete it altogether. In short how do I get back my old OS or What did Xen destroy in my system settings?

When I installed Xen also messed with  `/etc/network/interfaces`, which now looks like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Maybe that could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to remove Xen and its related packages with a simple:

```
sudo apt purge xen*
```

As for the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, that looks to be pretty standard for a machine with one network connection and using DHCP. If you have configurations in your `interfaces.d` directory, then you may need to add this to the the top of the file:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @matigo. When booting ubuntu  "Loading Xen 4.9-amd64 ..." is not displayed anymore. But it still takes ages (~5 min) compared to my pre-xen situation. So it seems that xen has nothing to do with the slow booting. I will accept your answer nevertheless, because it stopped the display of "Loading Xen ... ". However if you have some ideas what could have made my booting go so slow, let me know.